# "Padding invalid and cannot be removed" when encrypting using PKCS7 but works fine with Zeros

Tags: c#, encryption

cI wrote code for encrypting and decrypting byte[]. When I set the padding mode to PKCS7,I get an invalid padding error. Although, when I change the padding mode to Zeros, the encryption and decryption work just fine. Here is the code if anyone could take a look and see if they can point out the issue:

```
public static byte[] encryptBytes(byte[] plainText, string keyPath)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[plainText.Length];
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            byte[] tempKey, tempIV;
            int keySize = ((int)(new FileInfo(keyPath).Length)) - 16;
            readKeyIV(keyPath, keySize, out tempKey, out tempIV);
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.KeySize = keySize * 8;
            rijAlg.BlockSize = rijAlg.KeySize;
            rijAlg.Key = tempKey;
            rijAlg.IV = tempIV;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor();
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    //Write all data to the stream
                    csEncrypt.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                }
                cipherText = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
            return cipherText;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// takes a byte array of cipher text and a key then returns the decrypted byte array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipher"></param>
    /// <param name="keyPath"></param>
    public static byte[] decryptBytes(byte[] cipher, string keyPath)
    {
        if (cipher == null || cipher.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.Length];

        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {

            byte[] tempKey, tempIV;
            int keySize = ((int)(new FileInfo(keyPath).Length)) - 16;
            readKeyIV(keyPath, keySize, out tempKey, out tempIV);
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            rijAlg.KeySize = keySize * 8;
            rijAlg.BlockSize = rijAlg.KeySize;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Key = tempKey;
            rijAlg.IV = tempIV;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor();

            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    //Write all data to the stream
                    csEncrypt.Write(cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
                }
                plainText = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
            return plainText;
        }
    }
```

The key and IV are read from a file on the disk and generated before the functions are called. I did an extensive amount of research and found a few solution that I tried before posting this question and they didn't work for me.

1. FlushFinalBlock() didn't work
2. Setting the key size before the key and IV was already done
   There was a few more things I tried and didn't work but these were the major ones.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why it is wrong.

Edit: the problem happens when decrypting data. The way I test this is by reading a file and passing its content to the encryptBytes function, writing it to the disk in encrypted form, reading it back and feeding it to the decryptBytes function, and then storing the result on the disk in decrypted form. As I said, everything works great if I using Zeros padding but once I change that to PKCS7, it gives me that error. 
Thanks

Comment: The problem happens when encrypting or decrypting? in which line? are you testing with some pre-stored data or the data from encryptbytes is feeded to decryptbytes for testing?

Comment: Check that when you encrypt the file that you set the padding to PKCS7.  Do not rely on any system default, which might be different.  Explicitly set the padding to PKCS7.

Comment: `int keySize = ((int)(new FileInfo(keyPath).Length)) - 16;` What is the intent behind that line? Why don't you just use a fixed 16 or 32 bytes? That makes no sense and is likely responsible for your bug (PKCS#7 padding adds a block even if the initial file size is already a multiple of 16 bytes.)

Comment: Also, why are you coupling the block-size to the key-size?

Comment: The intent behind keySize is to make sure the key size is correct. For example if I generate a key of size 128 bits the keySize will have to be 16. If I generate a key of size 256 bits then it will need to be set to 32. There is a -16 in there because I also save the IV along with the key which is always 16 bytes. So, if the key was generated as 128 bits (16 bytes) along with the IV (16 bytes) the total size will be 32. When I read that key back it will have to be 32 - 16 = 16 bytes. Therefore, the key size is 16 bytes or 128 bits

Comment: I did make sure that the encryption padding is set to PKCS7 as well as the decryption.

Comment: I'm coupling block size to the key size because I want them to match. If the key size is 128 bits, then the block size is 128 bits. If the key size is 256 bits, then the block size is 256 bits. This is something I'm experimenting with for performance.